# Javascript access to other page

Tags: javascript

Can I have access from javascript on one page to elements on other page the script has created before? Something like this:

```
var win=window.open("http://www.ftwars.com/battle",'myWindow');
win.document.getElementById('center').onClick();
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply yes - you can , via variable reference, you cannot reach reference if you not created it in your javascript

Comment: In Opera I have mistake: "Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security error: attempted to read protected variable: getElementById". Do you know a browser where I can turn off security(I think this is the reason of error)?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. From the context you have given above, win is like any other object.

Answer (score 1):

First page (x.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var w = window.open('y.html', 'w');
    w.document.getElementById('target').onclick = function () { alert('!'); };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Second page (y.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <button id="target">target</button>
</body>
</html>
```